# Efficient way to track field completion funnel in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

What I want is to have a funnel reporting where users gave up a form, which fields they completed, and where did they go after they gave up.

Between my researches, I've found two ways of tracking this in Analytics. **The first one is creating for each field a virtual page**, triggering `_trackPageView` in completion, and making a goal with a funnel, that has the final page as a goal eg.: `/form/open-studio/received`, and the other fields as steps, for example: `/form/open-studio/name`, `/form/open-studio/email` (along with sending a form, `/form/open-studio/send`).

This solution was beautiful until I found out that this is inflating my page views report and decreasing the on-page time. I found in [this article](http://www.bluefountainmedia.com/blog/track-form-fields-pageviews-google-analytics/) a solution that involves creating a filter excluding pages that are in a `/form` "subdirectory" and creating another profile just to track these fields. Although, managing two accounts in JS and everything about this solution just doesn't feel right.

My question about this approach is: Is there a way to create some filter (globally or just in the reports) that doesn't count these `/form` pages as real page views, but still works to track the funnel?

**The second way I found was tracking field completion with events**. This solution looks more natural and organic. I could make a goal with a category of events for each form, and each field is a different action. The problems with this approach are: Each event triggered accomplishes a goal (which is not what I want), and GA doesn't seem to be able to create funnels out of events. I may be wrong (and I wish I am), but even this looking like the right option, this funnel report is very important for the client.

Which of these two is the "right approach"? Can I make this work without screwing up the other reports or having to sell my soul to a javascript GA code mess?

Also, if there is any other option instead of choosing between hell and limbo, please, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Heap Analytics. I think you will find it a better solution both for ease of implementation and ease of viewing results for what you're requesting. The process would be:

1. Create a Heap Analytics account. (Free 60 day trial.)
2. Add Heap Javascript snippet to your site. (Just copy and paste, you won't need to worry about implementing additional javascript on each field.)
3. Let it run for enough time to get a decent sample size (depends on the amount of traffic you get on your site).
4. Login to Heap Analytics and name the JS events on each page and each pageview.
5. Create a funnel from the named events to see where the problem is. You can also browse user paths on the Lists report and filtering by users who have done a particular action to see where they are going when they leave the form.